# Openshift project runs locally but not on the server

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, openshift

what i did is first i created a maven project, than added idex.xhtml file for JSF and changed the web.xml to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

After that deleted deleted JSP and html classes which i m not gonna need it. So when i try to run it locally i get the index page but when i run it on the web i get http status 404 not found. I committed and pushed my changes and made clean build before pushing. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking your logs to see where the problem is happening.

Best way is to ssh onto the gear and review the logs in ~/{cart_type}/logs